# A doubt regarding KL-divergence for estimating a distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, information-theory

Suppose given a probability distribution $q$. I'm trying to estimate it by $p$ such that the KL-divergence between $p$ and $q$ is minimized. Now which one of the two: $KL(p||q)$, $KL(q||p)$ should be minimized and why?

I understand that minimizing one of them will also minimize the other but for EM-like situation the first-one is used. I need some explanation for the same.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the definition [given by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), if we want to approximate a fixed distribution $Q$ with a tailor-made distribution $P$ we have to minimize 
$$ D_{KL}(Q\,||\,P)=\int_\mathbb{R}q(x)\log\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}\,dx.$$

Comment: I got the reason: $KL(q||p) = H(p,q) -H(q)$ where $H(p,q)$ $H(q,p)$ is the cross entropy of $q$ and $p$, and $H(q)$ is the entropy of $q$. Which gives the information lost when $p$ is used to approximate $q$